# How to get underlined text from active Word document?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a some word documents in an directory. i am developing a code in vb.net for extracting the text succeeding any underlined text from the word documents.

Is there any way to get underlined text from active word document using vb.net.

Comment: You could use a library like [Aspose Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) for this. It can process all kind of Word file formats. Stay away from Word Automation.

Comment: Someone's going to ask what you've tried. =)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use

```
pWordApp.Selection.Font.Underline = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle
```